# Different results with intermediate prints

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this function

```
def getDigits (num) :
    check = checkNum(num)
    #print('num: '+str(num))
    if check is False :
        strNum  = str(num)
        numList = map(toInt, strNum)
        #print(list(numList))
        squareList = map(getSquareOfDigits, numList)
        #print(list(squareList))
        sumOfSquares = sum(squareList)
        print('sumSqr: '+str(sumOfSquares))
        getDigits(sumOfSquares)
    else :
        return check
```

And the result of it is:

sumSqr: 4

sumSqr: 16

sumSqr: 37

sumSqr: 58

sumSqr: 89

sumSqr: 9

sumSqr: 81

sumSqr: 65

sumSqr: 61

sumSqr: 37

sumSqr: 58

sumSqr: 89

But if I uncomment all the prints, the result is:

```
[2]
[]
sumSqr: 0
[3]
[]
sumSqr: 0
```

ok, I know that the `list` method change the result, but I want to know it there's a way to print the object variables without changing the result, and not using an intermediate variable.

UPDATE

full example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53334716/first-return-works-the-second-doesnt)

Comment: Can you provide a complete and verifiable example? I suspect something unintended is going on with your return.

Comment: Traveler is talking [about this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How would we know, what `checkNum, toInt, getSquareOfDigits` do?

Answer (score 0):

The point is that `numList = map(toInt, strNum)` makes `numList` a [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map). After it has been iterated over once, it's exhausted and will no longer contain any values. The line `print(list(numList))` does exactly that by iterating over it, creating a list, printing a string representation of that list and then throwing everything away. If the print-line is commented, the iterator returned by `map` will generate values; with the `print` in-place, `numList` is effectively empty.

To prevent this, use `numList = list(map(toInt, strNum))`; that way, you have a persistent list-object which you can re-use.

Comment: ok, good answer. But, what if I want only to see an intermediate result and not add it to my code?

Comment: I honestly dont understand: Not add it to the code?

Comment: in php if I have doubs about what have after some code, I can do a print of the result and see it, without change the code execution, in JS I can do a console log, and so on... I want to do the same in python, see what I have in the middle of the execution without change the variable

Comment: As I said above, use `numList =  list(map(toInt, strNum))` instead of just `numList = map(...)`. This will cause `numList` to be a list-object, not an iterator. You can then `print(numList)` without side-effects.