# first return works, the second doesn't

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing the following exercise:

> A number chain is created by continuously added the square of the
>   digits of a number to form a new number until it has been seen
>   before.For example:
>
> 44 → 32 → 13 → 10 → 1 → 1
>
> 85 → 89 → 145 → 42 → 20 → 4 → 16 → 37 → 58 → 89
>
> Therefore any chain that arrives at 1 or 89 will become stuck in an
>   endless loop.
>
> What is most amazing is that EVERY starting number will eventually
>   arrive at 1 or 89.
>
> How many starting numbers below ten million will arrive at 89?

And my code just now is:

```
def start () :
    start_range = range(4)
    res = map(getDigits, start_range)
    print(list(res))

def getDigits (num) :
    check = checkNum(num)

    if check is False :
        strNum  = str(num)
        numList = map(toInt, strNum)
        squareList = map(getSquareOfDigits, numList)
        sumOfSquares = sum(squareList)
        getDigits(sumOfSquares)
    else :
        return check

def checkNum(num) :
    if num == 0 or num == 1 :
        print(type(num))
        print(num)
        return 0
    elif num == 89 :
        print(type(num))
        print(num)
        return 1
    else :
        return False

def toInt (char) :
    return int(char)

def getSquareOfDigits (num) :
    return num * num

start()
```

The output is

```
<class 'int'>
0
<class 'int'>
1
<class 'int'>
89
<class 'int'>
89
[0, 0, None, None]
```

And I don't understand why, if it goes correctly through the `elif` it doesn't return the '1' and add it correctly to the list.

Comment: Can you clarify how your result is different from what you were expecting? As you only print `type(num)` you always get `<class 'int'>`. Perhaps you wanted `print (type(check))` in `getDigits` instead? That will print the occasional `<class 'bool'>`.

Answer (score 1):

In recursive functions you must have return values in your recursive call

```
def getDigits (num) :
    check = checkNum(num)

    if check is False :
        strNum  = str(num)
        numList = map(toInt, strNum)
        squareList = map(getSquareOfDigits, numList)
        sumOfSquares = sum(squareList)
  ---------> return getDigits(sumOfSquares)
    else :
        return check
```